# Vue - how to bind table column to a data object?

Tags: html-table, vue.js

I'm new to Vue, so go easy on me! Here's the situation. There must be a better way than what I'm doing here.

I have a simple 2 column HTML table:

```html
<table id="contacts">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="column-1">
            Contact Id
        </th>
        <th class="column-2">
            Applications assigned count
        </th>       
    </tr>
      <tr class="odd" id="contacts_tr_1">
 <td class="column-1">
      1
      </td>
 <td class="column-2">
      247
      </tr>
      <tr class="even last" id="contacts_tr_2">
 <td class="column-1">
      2
      </td>
 <td class="column-2">
     0
      </td>
  </tr>
      <tr class="even last" id="contacts_tr_2">
 <td class="column-1">
      3
      </td>
 <td class="column-2">
     44
      </td>
  </tr>
        <tr class="even last" id="contacts_tr_2">
 <td class="column-1">
      .........
      </td>
 <td class="column-2">
     .........
      </td>
  </tr>

      <tr class="even last" id="contacts_tr_2">
 <td class="column-1">
      10
      </td>
 <td class="column-2">
     76
      </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

I want to update the "Applications assigned count" column (but only for certain rows), as determined by the result of an AJAX call. So assuming the table has 10 rows, the AJAX call might say that the value of the "Applications assigned count" column of rows 1, 4 and 7 need to be updated, to e.g. 247, 80 and 356 respectively. I'm thinking of using a JSON object like this as my Vue data object, because the AJAX response will look like this.

```
  data: {
    num_of_applications_assigned: [
        {
            "party_id": "1",
            "num": "247"},
        {
            "party_id": "4",
            "num": "80"},
        {
            "party_id": "7",
            "num": "356"}

    ]
  },
```

I thought there might be a way to bind the "Applications assigned count" column to the Vue data object that gets updated by the AJAX call, but I don't see a way to do this other than adding a unique v-text to each individual `<TD>` cell e.g.

```
<div v-text="num_of_applications_assigned_1"></div>
<div v-text="num_of_applications_assigned_2"></div>
etc
```

However, this has lead me to writing some very convoluted code when updating those v-texts with the results of the AJAX response, as I have to dynamically construct the references:

```
 let vm = this;
    jQuery.ajax({
            url: myurl
        }).then(function(response) {                
           for (var i = 0, len = vm.num_of_applications_assigned.length; i < len; i++) {
            var party_id = vm.num_of_applications_assigned[i].party_id;
            var dref = 'vm.num_of_applications_assigned_'+party_id;
            var dnum = vm.num_of_applications_assigned[i].num;
            eval(dref + ' = ' + dnum + ';');
           }           
    });
```

Yes, I know **eval is bad** - that's why I'm here asking for help! What is a better way of doing this, or is Vue not a good match for this situation?

Comment: Use v-for directive and yeah vue is reactive, all you need to do is have your data updated with results from the Ajax call and the table would rerender with the updates.

Comment: I don't think I can use v-for in this case, as the table rows are pre-created on the server. I can add stuff to individual rows or cells though. What do you propose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't use v-for, as the table and its rows are all generated server side

If you cannot use `v-for` you can still use Vue to render your data, if you decide to do some additional work on the server-side, and you mould your data a little differently. It's less elegant than `v-for` but it should be straightforward.

For example, if you wanted to create a two-column table where Vue would render/update the second column's cell values, you could generate something like this on the server side:

```
<table id="app">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>{{ applications.party_1.num }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td> 
        <td>{{ applications.party_2.num }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Where you use your favourite server-side language to generate values `party_1`, `party_2`, `party_3` dynamically.

This implies that an underlying data structure like so:

```
applications: {
  party_1: { num: 1 },
  party_2: { num: 2 }
}
```

This should be straightforward to create that structure dynamically on the server-side. Then, just create a Vue instance and populate its initial `data` object with that data structure:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    applications: {
      party_1: { num: 1 },
      party_2: { num: 2 }
    }
  }
});
```

When the HTML is rendered in a browser, the Vue instance mounts and it will update the bound cell values from its `data` object. These values are reactive, so any subsequent changes to the Vue instance's underlying data will be rendered automatically.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The idea in Vue is to have all your data ready, and let Vue.JS do the rendering. So, your data should probably look like this:

```
data: {
   assignedApplications: [
    { party_id: 1, num: 247 },
    { party_id: 2, num: 0 },
    { party_id: 3, num: 44 },
    { party_id: 4, num: 76 },
    { party_id: 5, num: 9 },
   ]
  },
}
```

Then, you can let Vue render it:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="column-1">Contact Id</th>
        <th class="column-2">Applications assigned count</th>       
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="a in assignedApplications">
        <td>{{a.party_id}}</td>
        <td>{{a.num}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Remains the problem, how to update it. After getting the new data, you have to modify the array `this.assignedApplications`, and then Vue will re-render the table correctly. If your rows have a unique id, you could make assignedApplications instead of an array a map-like data structure, so you can easy access specific rows by their id and change the value. If not, you have to search through the whole array for every change and adapt it:

```
mergeInNewData(newData) {
    for (let i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
        let changedData = newData[i];
        for (let j = 0; j < this.assignedApplications.length; j++) {
            if (this.assignedApplications[j].party_id === changedData.party_id) {
                this.assignedApplications[j].num = changedData.num;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All together, an example could look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
   <table>
   <tr>
    <th class="column-1">Contact Id</th>
    <th class="column-2">Applications assigned count</th>       
   </tr>
   <tr v-for="a in assignedApplications">
    <td>{{a.party_id}}</td>
    <td>{{a.num}}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="update">Update</a>
 </div>

  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        assignedApplications: [
         { party_id: 1, num: 247 },
         { party_id: 2, num: 0 },
         { party_id: 3, num: 44 },
         { party_id: 4, num: 76 },
         { party_id: 5, num: 9 },
        ]
      },
      methods: {
       update: function() {
        let newData = [
         { party_id: 1, num: 243},
         { party_id: 2, num: 80},
         { party_id: 4, num: 0},
        ];
        this.mergeInNewData(newData);
       },
       mergeInNewData(newData) {
        for (let i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
         let changedData = newData[i];
         for (let j = 0; j < this.assignedApplications.length; j++) {
          if (this.assignedApplications[j].party_id === changedData.party_id) {
           this.assignedApplications[j].num = changedData.num;
          }
         }
        }
       }
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I really do appreciate it. Unfortunately, I really think I can't use v-for, as the table and its rows are all generated server side (the actual table I will be using is much more complex than this example). As I said in my question, I'm really thinking that Vue is not a good for for my situation. I might have to fall back on jQuery to update those column values.